# Maven 3 Multi Module build tries to run targets on the Multi Module POM itself

Tags: maven, pom.xml, multi-module

I have several projects that all have a similar Maven build. Each of the project POMs extend from a parent POM containing all of the common dependencies, plugins, etc. that are available to each project. I also have a multi-module POM, currently separate from the parent POM. The purpose of this multi-module POM is to have a single place I can run a target on all of the modules with one command.

If I try to run a plugin, say JS Duck, off of the multi-module POM, I get the following output (project names changed for simplicity):

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Project 1 .......................................... SUCCESS [7.850s]
[INFO] Project 2 .......................................... SUCCESS [0.803s]
[INFO] Project 3 .......................................... SUCCESS [8.488s]
[INFO] Multi-Module POM ................................... FAILURE [0.477s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.780s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 14 09:31:52 EST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jsduck' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories
```

It fails because I don't have the JS Duck plugin specified in my multi-module POM.

**Why is it trying to run the plugin on the multi-module POM at all?**

I can go the other route and include the modules in my parent POM instead of having a separate multi-module POM, but that has a different problem. In that case, the build succeeds because this time the JS Duck plugin is declared in the multi-module/parent POM. However, it runs the JS Duck plugin against the multi-module/parent POM which essentially generates a garbage 'target' directory because there is no code there to analyze.

For reference, my project structure is:

```
dev
|- Project1
   |- pom.xml
|- Project2
   |- pom.xml
|- Project3
   |- pom.xml
|- pom.xml (parent POM)
|- all-pom.xml (multi-module POM)
```

Is there any recommended suggestions in this situation? Is there any way to stop Maven from trying to build the multi-module POM itself? Maybe a different `<packaging>` type that would do that?

Thanks for your suggestions!

[EDIT]

Here is the all-pom.xml... some details changed for privacy.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.nate</groupId>
  <artifactId>projects-all</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Multi-Module POM</name>
  <description>Builds all projects</description>

  <modules>
      <module>Project1</module>
      <module>Project2</module>
      <module>Project3</module>
  </modules>

  <repositories>
    ...
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
     ...
  </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

And here is the parent POM... including the addition of child modules.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.nate.pom</groupId>
  <artifactId>js-master</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>JavaScript Project POM</name>
  <description>Parent POM for all JavaScript projects.</description>

  <!-- inherit license and other company-wide configuration -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.nate</groupId>
    <artifactId>master</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </parent>

  <modules>
      <module>Project1</module>
      <module>Project2</module>
      <module>Project3</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
      <release.version>1.0.0</release.version>
  </properties>

  <scm>
    ...
  </scm>
  <issueManagement>
    ...
  </issueManagement>
  <ciManagement>
    ...
  </ciManagement>
  <developers>
    ...
  </developers>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/js</sourceDirectory>
  </build>

 <profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>javascript</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>

      <properties>
        ...
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
        ...
      </dependencies>

      <build>
        <plugins>
          ...
          <plugin>
            <groupId>nl.secondfloor.mojo.jsduck</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsduck-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
              <javascriptDirectory>src/main/js</javascriptDirectory>
              <targetDirectory>target/site/api</targetDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <repositories>
    ...
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    ...
  </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: First the thing *all-pom.xml* looks wrong, cause either your build is a multi-module build or not. Use the pom.xml( parent pom) and define the appropriate modules in it.

Comment: That's what I describe as the second option... but it still tries to run JS Duck on the parent POM, which doesn't make sense because there's nothing to do there... it's type 'pom'.

Comment: From where did you start your build ? In the dev/pom.xml level ?

Comment: Can you show the pom.xml file ?

Comment: POMs have been added - some details removed for privacy.

Comment: Why do you define repositories in your pom?

Comment: The company I work for has a central Artifactory repository where libraries from other projects get deployed to. We depend on some of those libraries, and, as such, need to let Maven know about the company repository so that it can find them.

Comment: It would be better to configure this in the Artifactory instead of in the pom.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - Maven has to know how to find our Artifactory instance - that's what the repositories tags specify.

Comment: Ah sorry. Better put such kind of configuration into the settings.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly deactivate the plugin in the all-pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>nl.secondfloor.mojo.jsduck</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsduck-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel, this is useful to know. However, in order to re-enable the plugin for all of the children, I'd have to re-declare the plugin in each of the child POMs, right? That would defeat the purpose of specifying it in the all-pom in the first place. Let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: If you declare the plugin in the parent, and that your projects inherit from the parent, but that all-pom does NOT inherit from the parent, you should have the plugin run in all your modules, but not in the all-pom, with only 2 declarations.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry - it had been a while since I had posted this and I got confused because we now just use the one parent pom which is a multi-module pom as well. Your suggestion may very well work.

Comment: I never used a POM that was parent AND multi-module, but my multi-module POM used to inherit from the Parent, and ... this was a mess. Since I removed thos inheritance, things are much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The pom which contains the modules list:

```
<modules>
  <module>..</module>
  ..
</modules>
```

must have the packaging type *pom*.

Comment: It does have packaging type 'pom'.