# Maven release using multi-module pom

Tags: java, maven

We have many, many different modules that make up different builds. I thought it may be a good idea to create a multi-module pom listing all the modules that would make up a specifc ear.

This post describes reasonably well what I am trying to achieve:
[Maven 3 Multi Module build tries to run targets on the Multi Module POM itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881050/maven-3-multi-module-build-tries-to-run-targets-on-the-multi-module-pom-itself?rq=1)

Essentially we have a master pom that defines all the common modules, spring etc.

I have created a separate multi module pom that creates all the modules for a specific build. I want to release all the modules in the modules section but dont want to release the actual multi-module pom itself.

I'm using a command line like:

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare -DdryRun=true release:update-versions -f My-Multi-Module-1.pom
```

but this is failing rtrying to release the My-Multi-Module-1.pom.

Can this be done?

Comment: Why don't you want to release the multi-module pom itself? As it is part of the same source tree, it will get tagged/labelled along with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
-pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified
                                       reactor projects to build instead
                                       of all projects. A project can be
                                       specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                       or by its relative path.
```